# MissingManifestException in mscorlib.dll on IMessageService.ShowXXXX

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, resources, catel

In my view model, I have a IMessageService, which is initialized in the constructor:

```
private IMessageService messageService;
public MyViewModel()
{
    messageService = ServiceLocator.Default.ResolveType<IMessageService>();
}
```

Its `Show` method works, but ShowError, ShowInformation and ShowWarning (anything in need of a resource, here the icons) crash with a `MissingManifestException` pointing towards `Catel.Properties.Resources.resources` manifest.

Is the error on my side (wrongly installed Catel) or is it because it's the .Net 4.0 version of Catel? Surprisingly, I have another Catel for .Net 4.0 project which doesn't show this error.

EDIT: `Show`, when given a `MessageImage`, works flawlessly and does show the icon.

EDIT 2: Nevermind my last edit, everything now seems to work... for no reason. Calling `Show` with a `MessageImage` would have "loaded" the resource or something? That seems unlikely.

Comment: Tip #1: inject your services instead of resolving them in the ctor

Comment: @Geert I feel like we already had this discussion before :) I can't quite use all Catel's magic, as documentation seems to be a bit chaotic amongst versions and extensions of Catel; put shortly, I'm just lost, so I do with what I know :p

Comment: public MyViewModel(IMessageService messageService)
{

}

Comment: Yes, I remember that, and I remember it not working since I'm not using catel:DataWindow (for various reasons that would just need to go in another question: it fits to content, it has buttons which force you to pass the `Custom` mode, VS graphic editor sometimes hates it, and lots of things I'd have to learn).

Comment: Even in such a case you should use IViewModelFactory to create your view models manually (which support dependency injection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the source: **CLR Exception breaking** in debug mode.

It looks like **Catel** sometimes throw some **handled exceptions**, and if you have Common Language Runtime checked in your exceptions settings (*Visual Studio menu > Debug > Exception...*), your debugger will break on these.

That's not so bad, just hit **F5** (`Continue`) to get through.

What puzzled me was that this `MissingManifestException` broke again after hitting F5. The fact is that it seems to **break for multiple resource icons**, looking like it just keep on breaking like a real unhandled exception.

But no, so **if you ever get a Catel exception, keep on hitting F5 or disable the CLR exceptions breaking**.

Edit: as [Geert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/561411/geert-van-horrik) suggest, you indeed don't need to disable every CLR exception breaking... Just disable the MissingManifestException.

Comment: You can disable the specific MissingManifestException. This is because the LanguageService tries to be smart and get the right language from any resource.

Comment: @Geert indeed, I don't know why I suggest to disable them all