# How to separate a ViewModel in multiple?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, .net-4.0, catel

Following on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210940/missingmanifestexception-in-mscorlib-dll-on-imessageservice-showxxxx/28211250#28211250)'s comments, I feel obliged to ask this one.

It's an application I'm currently working on, and to avoid further issues and to keep on working with Catel (which, whatever troubles I may have with it, is really pleasant to use), I will need explanations on a few topics.

---

I have an API class (let's call it `API`) which contains several methods to connect to some content manager and perform actions on it.
It's a single class that I'd like to split into several `Model` classes (for the example, two will do):

- `Connection` : pretty self-explanatory, would contain two `Commands` calling `API.Connect` and `API.Disconnect`
- `DataSource` : indicates where/on what in the content manager the application will be work, with one `Command` calling `API.LoadDataSource`

As far as the models go, it's ok, nothing too hard. My first issue comes with the associated `ViewModels`; I need to use the same instance of `API` in every single of these. So for now, I use only one ViewModel, and the `UserControls` associated with my `Models` just inherit it from my `MainWindow` (these are regular UserControls, not Catel's, else it yells at me for not having ViewModels for them).

Since Catel isn't too fond of nested viewmodels, here's my question:

**How do I pass/use a parameter between various ViewModels?** (or *how do I separate my main ViewModel without using nested viewmodels?*)

Comment: Tons of different ways.  Like using IoC containers to manage instances and deliver dependencies.  Or instantiate your api as a resource in app.xaml and then bind it to your view models.  More ways to do it than not to do it.

Comment: @Will that's my issue: I don't know how. I searched, I saw a lot of things, I don't know which ones are related to the others, I'm plainly lost.

Comment: Tons of different ways.  Pick one.  It's easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I need to persist state in an application, I use services for this. View models are a representation of a view, and will only live while the view is active / visible. State goes beyond that, it needs to be managed throughout the whole app in different view models.

Therefore I always choose to have a service that holds the state. This service is registered in the ServiceLocator (IoC container) and will be injected into the view models via dependency injection.

This way you can always retrieve the information when you load the view models. The best way to do this is in the *Initialize* method (you should subscribe your events here as well). You should clean up your view models (unsubscribing events) in the *Close* method of the view model.

Comment: Looks good; I can implement my service any way I want, right? I thought I would have to implement some Catel's interface, but looking at `IMessageService` and `MessageService` sources, it doesn't seem to be the case. Yet, I don't see which events you're talking about; **should** I have special events, or are you just referring to WPF events? And, in a MVVM point of view, can services have knowledge of models?

Comment: The "events" you are talking about are methods on the view models (just override them). Services have nothing to do with Catel. Catel does implement a lot of stuff as services though so you can easily replace a default implementation by your own.

Comment: Ok then, thanks a bunch. I'll be sure to annoy you again soon :p